# React JS use bootstrap carousel multiple times in a page with reactstrap

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I am struggled with using bootstrap carousel multiple times in a page.

I have tried lot with copy as a new item, but its shows error all time.

https://reactstrap.github.io/components/carousel/

```
<CarouselItem
  onExiting={() => setAnimating(true)}
  onExited={() => setAnimating(false)}
  key={item.src}
>
  <img src={item.src} alt={item.altText} />
  <CarouselCaption captionText={item.caption} captionHeader={item.caption} />
</CarouselItem>
```

..

```
<CarouselItem
  onExiting={() => setAnimating(true)}
  onExited={() => setAnimating(false)}
  key={item2.src}
>
  <img src={item2.src} alt={item2.altText} />
  <CarouselCaption captionText={item2.caption} captionHeader={item2.caption} />
</CarouselItem>
```

Is it need to copy the entire things again?

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-wilbur-yeonm?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I see no error in your sandbox, did you mean the warning in console log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just copy the Carousel component along with the variables and event handlers like so: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-ellis-43cbz?file=/src/App.js

A `CarouselItem` is an image. The entire carousel itself is the `Carousel` component.

If you need the carousels to work independently, you should create separate variables and handlers for each carousel.

Comment: This seems both slider are working together when click next/prev buttons.. I need it as a new carousel with new images etc.

Comment: @vishnu You need separate handlers/variables for `activeIndex`, `next`, `previous`, `activeIndex`, `activeIndex`, and `goToIndex`. I'll update the sandbox. Give me a second.

Comment: it would be great if you can help me.. Im noob on React JS :(

Comment: @vishu Check it now https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-ellis-43cbz?file=/src/App.js

Comment: okay.. so it is necessary to copy everything again.. right? can we use it as an array or something? to reduce code?

Comment: @vishnu Yes. What you _could_ do is `.map()` the `items` out from a multidimensional array into your JSX, but for all intents and purposes, this should work just fine. Here's how to do that if you want, but the code from the CodePen works as-is. https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: @vishnu you would still have to create separate event handlers, though, so this is probably the optimal solution.

Comment: checking with my code & let you know if it is working.. :)

Comment: @vishnu For example, if you wanted to do something like 12 carousels, then you should consider using `.map()` inside of your JSX. As a general rule, you should try to keep component files under 1000 lines long.